# In R, how to take each row of dataframe and give it its own columns

Tags: r, tidyr

I work for the government, and they like their data messy. I have (many) tidy datasets (one example below), that I would like to make messy so I can put it into one of their stupid excel files... sort of like a pivot_wider, but not quite. The reprex below gives what I am after, but I am sure there must be a better way i.e. (works for any number of rows)

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

dat <- structure(list(`Industry (aggregate)` = c("Public Administration",
                                          "Health Care And Social Assistance", "Educational Services",
                                          "Professional, Scientific And Technical Services", "Repair, Personal And Non-Profit Services"
), jo = c(530, 70, 60, 10, 10), `%` = c(0.78, 0.1, 0.09, 0.01,
                                        0.01)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                        ))

splatten <- function(tbbl){
  first <- tbbl[1,]
  second <- tbbl[2,]
  third <- tbbl[3,]
  fourth <- tbbl[4,]
  fifth <- tbbl[5,]
  bind_cols(first, second, third, fourth, fifth)
}

splatten(dat)
#> New names:
#> • `Industry (aggregate)` -> `Industry (aggregate)...1`
#> • `jo` -> `jo...2`
#> • `%` -> `%...3`
#> • `Industry (aggregate)` -> `Industry (aggregate)...4`
#> • `jo` -> `jo...5`
#> • `%` -> `%...6`
#> • `Industry (aggregate)` -> `Industry (aggregate)...7`
#> • `jo` -> `jo...8`
#> • `%` -> `%...9`
#> • `Industry (aggregate)` -> `Industry (aggregate)...10`
#> • `jo` -> `jo...11`
#> • `%` -> `%...12`
#> • `Industry (aggregate)` -> `Industry (aggregate)...13`
#> • `jo` -> `jo...14`
#> • `%` -> `%...15`
#> # A tibble: 1 × 15
#>   Industry (aggregate)...…¹ jo...2 `%...3` Industry (aggregate)…² jo...5 `%...6`
#>   <chr>                      <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>                   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 Public Administration        530    0.78 Health Care And Socia…     70     0.1
#> # ℹ abbreviated names: ¹​`Industry (aggregate)...1`, ²​`Industry (aggregate)...4`
#> # ℹ 9 more variables: `Industry (aggregate)...7` <chr>, jo...8 <dbl>,
#> #   `%...9` <dbl>, `Industry (aggregate)...10` <chr>, jo...11 <dbl>,
#> #   `%...12` <dbl>, `Industry (aggregate)...13` <chr>, jo...14 <dbl>,
#> #   `%...15` <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Perhaps `t(dat)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dat |>
  mutate(row = row_number()) |>
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = row,
              values_from = c(`Industry (aggregate)`, jo, `%`), 
              names_vary = "slowest")
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 1 × 15
  `Industry (aggregate)_1`  jo_1 `%_1` `Industry (aggregate)_2`           jo_2 `%_2` `Industry (aggregate)_3`  jo_3 `%_3` `Industry (aggregate)_4`                         jo_4 `%_4` `Industry (aggregate)_5`                  jo_5 `%_5`
  <chr>                    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                             <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                                           <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                                    <dbl> <dbl>
1 Public Administration      530  0.78 Health Care And Social Assistance    70   0.1 Educational Services        60  0.09 Professional, Scientific And Technical Services    10  0.01 Repair, Personal And Non-Profit Services    10  0.01
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a close approximation:

```r
out <- do.call(cbind, split.data.frame(dat, 1:nrow(dat)))
names(out) <- make.unique(rep(names(dat), times = ncol(out) / ncol(dat)))
out
#    Industry (aggregate)  jo    %            Industry (aggregate).1 jo.1 %.1 Industry (aggregate).2 jo.2  %.2                          Industry (aggregate).3 jo.3  %.3                   Industry (aggregate).4 jo.4  %.4
# 1 Public Administration 530 0.78 Health Care And Social Assistance   70 0.1   Educational Services   60 0.09 Professional, Scientific And Technical Services   10 0.01 Repair, Personal And Non-Profit Services   10 0.01
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list("Industry (aggregate)" = c("Public Administration", "Health Care And Social Assistance", "Educational Services", "Professional, Scientific And Technical Services", "Repair, Personal And Non-Profit Services"), jo = c(530, 70, 60, 10, 10), "%" = c(0.78, 0.1, 0.09, 0.01, 0.01)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```